# How to get all records of today date through Hibernate HSQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hsqldb

I am trying to get all record of today date through the below HSQL query

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("findUsersOrder")
            .setTimestamp("todayDate", date);
```

and query in db table is

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "findUsersOrder", query = "FROM GroupTweetOrder WHERE gtoAddedDate = :todayDate "),


})
```

But it is returning zero record ....

Can someone tell me how to get all records of current date or today date only?

**Updated**

> SEVERE: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of
>   range: 0  at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CharacterTypeDescriptor.wrap(CharacterTypeDescriptor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CharacterTypeDescriptor.wrap(CharacterTypeDescriptor.java:33)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:66)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:65)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:269)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:265)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:357)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2701)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1541)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1473)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1373)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:640)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:850)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2447)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2433)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2263)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2258)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1161)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)     at
>   com.ccc.spring.dao.GroupDistDAO.fetchTodayGroupOrder(GroupDistDAO.java:82)
>     at
>   com.ccc.spring.service.GroupDistService.fetchTodayGroupOrder(GroupDistService.java:40)
>     at
>   com.ccc.spring.service.GroupDistService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a552f952.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
>     at
>   com.ccc.spring.service.GroupDistService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbd2ed38.fetchTodayGroupOrder()
>     at
>   com.ccc.managedController.TweetDistributionManagedBean.sendGroupTweets(TweetDistributionManagedBean.java:175)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)   at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> Jun 23, 2014 3:17:49 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl
>   log SEVERE: JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught
>   during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 :
>   UIComponent-ClientId=formcontract:iconOnly,
>   Message=java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of
>   range: 0 Jun 23, 2014 3:17:49 PM
>   com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl log SEVERE:
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   0 javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException:
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   0     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:182)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   0     at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CharacterTypeDescriptor.wrap(CharacterTypeDescriptor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CharacterTypeDescriptor.wrap(CharacterTypeDescriptor.java:33)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:66)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:65)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:269)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:265)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:357)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2701)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1541)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1473)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1373)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:640)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:850)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2447)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2433)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2263)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2258)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1161)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)     at
>   com.ccc.spring.dao.GroupDistDAO.fetchTodayGroupOrder(GroupDistDAO.java:82)
>     at
>   com.ccc.spring.service.GroupDistService.fetchTodayGroupOrder(GroupDistService.java:40)
>     at
>   com.ccc.spring.service.GroupDistService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a552f952.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
>     at
>   com.ccc.spring.service.GroupDistService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbd2ed38.fetchTodayGroupOrder()
>     at
>   com.ccc.managedController.TweetDistributionManagedBean.sendGroupTweets(TweetDistributionManagedBean.java:175)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)   at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
>     ... 31 more
>
> Hibernate: select grouptweet0_.gto_id as gto1_15_,
>   grouptweet0_.gto_added_date as gto2_15_, grouptweet0_.gto_email_id as
>   gto3_15_, grouptweet0_.gto_group_count as gto4_15_,
>   grouptweet0_.gto_send as gto5_15_, grouptweet0_.gto_send_date as
>   gto6_15_, grouptweet0_.gto_user_active as gto7_15_,
>   grouptweet0_.gto_user_id as gto8_15_ from
>   subodhc_ccc.group_tweet_order grouptweet0_ where
>   grouptweet0_.gto_added_date>=? and grouptweet0_.gto_added_date

Comment: What types are the `gtoAddedDate` field/`date` variable? Does either of them include a time of day that may differ from the other?

Comment: gtoAddedDate is a Db column of timestamp type

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JodaTime library to get the best out of Data functions. You can do it with plaing Java 6 or 7 too, but it's much more work to get the timestamp of the current day at midnight.

With JodaTime this is how you can do it:

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "findUsersOrder", query = "FROM GroupTweetOrder WHERE gtoAddedDate >= :todayAtMidnight and gtoAddedDate < :tomorrowAtMidnight")
})

DateTime todayAtMidnight = new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime tomorrowAtMidnight = todayAtMidnight.plusDays(1);

Query query = session.getNamedQuery("findUsersOrder")
        .setTimestamp("todayAtMidnight", todayAtMidnight.toDate())
        .setTimestamp("tomorrowAtMidnight", tomorrowAtMidnight.toDate());
```

Comment: I am getting this exception SEVERE: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Comment: You need to post the full stack trace, otherwise it's difficult to track what's going on.

Comment: Added full stack trace

Comment: You have an empty CHAR field that is mapped to a String and it should probably contain a one letter entry or null. In your case it returned an empty String.

Comment: Try running the query in your DB sql console and see what results it fetches.

Comment: But another answer saying issue is with `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) ` it is deprecated by hibernate

Comment: Here is query `Select * from group_tweet_order where gto_added_date  >='2014-06-23T00:00:00.000+05:30' and gto_added_date < '2014-06-24T00:00:00.000+05:30'` look like working fine so somewhere else issue coming

Comment: So the original question is answered.

Comment: No its not a solution as HSQL throwing exception after this change